# Symbol could not be found

Tags: java

I try to call the `Accumulator` class in my program, but the symbol cannot be found.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Login c = new Login();
    Accumulator d = new Accumulator();
    ^                   ^
}
```

Comment: _It cannot find the symbol._ `Accumulator` class is not exists in your classpath..

Comment: can u give me example how to make an classpath (newbie here)

Comment: Try to "import namepackage. Accumulator;"

Comment: Is `Accumulator` class predefined or user defined. If it is predefined, try to `import` the package in your current class and add the jar file that contains `Accumulator` class to your classpath. if it is user-defined then just `import` the package.

Comment: Use Google for how to set classpath...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the `Accumulator` class is from. Did you write it yourself? Then you can either use your IDE or look into the `Accumulator` class to find out its package. For example, if you had this class:

```
package com.myapp;

public class Accumulator
{
    // some code here
}
```

You would then have to declare an `import` statement in the class you want to use `Accumulator`, like this:

```
package com.myapp.other.package;

import com.myapp.Accumulator;

public class OtherClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Login c = new Login();
        Accumulator d = new Accumulator();
    }
}
```